# Can I omit 'and' in this case?

Tags: usage

If instead of 'to say and assume that...,' I write 'to say that I assume that...' do these sentences mean the same?

Does

> That is so weird ***to say and assume that*** you meant something else and had made a mistake.

mean the same with

> That is so weird ***to say that I would assume that*** you meant something else and had made a mistake.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is the "and" you want to omit?

Comment: My question is the one I omit 'and,' and 'and' between 'say' and 'assume' is what I'm try to omit.

Comment: But your sentence doesn't have "say and assume".

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please give us the source of the original sentence. Did you write it? If not, where did you find it (please give a link if possible)? Why do you wish to change it?  The more you explain, the easier will it be for us to understand your question and help you with it.